# How do i get rid of these escape characters. Looking for some sort of regex

Tags: regex, sed, terminal, escaping, ansi-escape

I am trying to output the output of neofetch to a discord embed for a project of mine. Is there any easy way to get rid of that escape sequence at the start and end of the embed.

the command i used to generate the output is `neofetch --off --color_blocks off | sed 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z]//g'`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those escape sequences are color codes.

You can use the `--stdout` option to disable all coloring:

```
neofetch --off --color_blocks off --stdout
```

See `neofetch --help`:

> OTHER:
> ...
> `--stdout`                    Turn off all colors and disables any ASCII/image backend.